# Trouble with integration in order to find analytic function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let $u(x,y) = x/(x^2 - y^2)$

Find $v(x,y)$ such that $f(z) = u + iv$

---

I'm applying Cauchy-Riemann
$u_x = -\frac{(x^2 - y^2)}{(x^2 + y^2)} = v_y$

But I don't see how to integrate that with respect to $y$.

Comment: Find $u_x$ properly......

Comment: Is $f$ analytic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note :** See that here $u$ is **NOT** harmonic. So there does not exist any analytic function $f=u+iv$ , where , $u=\frac{x}{x^2-y^2}$.